# Finding all columns in data frame of a certain value by row

Tags: r, dataframe, row, data-manipulation

I am trying to find the first column that has a specific number and the last column of the same value by each row in a dataframe. See example data and desired output if the number was 4.

Example Data

```
ID WZ_1 WZ_2 WZ_3 WZ_4
1  5    4    4    3 
2  4    4    3    3
3  4    4    4    4
```

Example Output

```
ID First Last 
1  WZ_2  WZ_3
2  WZ_1  WZ_2
3  WZ_1  WZ_4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

# dummy data
# use setDT(df) if yours isn't a datatable already
df <- data.table(id = 1:3
                 , a = c(4,4,0)
                 , b = c(0,4,0)
                 , c = c(4,0,4)
                 ); df
   id a b c
1:  1 4 0 4
2:  2 4 4 0
3:  3 0 0 4

# find 1st & last column with target value
df[, .(id
       , first = apply(.SD, 1, \(i) names(df)[min(which(i==4))])
       , last = apply(.SD, 1, \(i) names(df)[max(which(i==4))])
       )
   ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Alaina if this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. (You can also upvote it if you found it helpful.)

Comment: Still. Thanks, zephryl, AndrewGB and Alaina

Answer (score 2):

With `max.col`:

```r
data.frame(ID = df$ID,
           First = names(df)[max.col(df == 4, ties.method = "first")],
           Last = names(df)[max.col(df == 4, ties.method = "last")])

  ID First Last
1  1  WZ_2 WZ_3
2  2  WZ_1 WZ_2
3  3  WZ_1 WZ_4
```

data

```r
df <- read.table(header= T, text= "ID WZ_1 WZ_2 WZ_3 WZ_4
1  5    4    4    3 
2  4    4    3    3
3  4    4    4    4 ")
```

Comment: It also works with `dplyr`: `df %>% mutate(First = names(.)[max.col(. == 4, ties.method = "first")], Last = names(.)[max.col(. == 4, ties.method = "last")])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` option, where I put into long form, then `filter` to keep only the values with `4` and only the first and last occurrence. Then, I create a new column to denote whether it is the first or last value, then pivot back to the wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(value == 4) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n()) %>% 
  mutate(col = c("First", "Last")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col", values_from = "name") %>% 
  select(-value)
```

**Output**

```
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 WZ_2  WZ_3 
2     2 WZ_1  WZ_2 
3     3 WZ_1  WZ_4
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, WZ_1 = c(5L, 4L, 4L), WZ_2 = c(4L, 4L, 
4L), WZ_3 = c(4L, 3L, 4L), WZ_4 = c(3L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```